# python inspect как можно получить список имен/переменных используемых в данной функции

Tags: python, инспекция-кода

Как используя модуль inspect получить список имен переменных используемых в данной функции (внутри выполнения самой функции или извне)

```
import inspect    # модуль для интроспекции живых обьектов


def save_svodka_shassi():
    """
    Сохранение введенных данных в Combo_boxes в БД таблицу 'SVODKA_SHASSI'
    """
    peremenaya_1 = 'test_1'   # !!!
    peremenaya_2 = 114        # !!!
    peremenaya_3 = None
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/inspect.html

Comment: )).............

Comment: Какая у вас задача? Зачем вам локальные переменные? Я спрашиваю потому что обычно задачи, которые требуют рефлексии могут быть решены более традиционными методами.

Comment: таких переменных ожидается очень много и я бы хотел, чтобы переменным значение, которых например пустое/None присвоить значение какое нибудь по-умолчанию ! Значения переменных получаю извне с GUI (PYQT5). Не хотелось бы явно указывать каждую переменную и проверять значение для каждой переменной

Comment: Условно: если обнаружены локальные переменные и у них отсутсвует значение/None , то присвоить значение такой переменной по-умолчанию !

Comment: Зачем тогда отдельные переменные? Храните их как ключи в словаре.

Comment: а что даст хранение этих переменных как ключей ? не совсем понимаю / ?

Comment: Если вы в этой функции цикл заведёте `for i ...`, `i` попадёт в `locals`. Вы её на общих основаниях обрабатывать будете? Это только один из тысячи возможных примеров. Вы затрудняете написание логики с использованием переменных в этой функции. А словарь отделяет данные, которые вы хотите обрабатывать отдельно от служебных переменных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inspect даже и не нужен

```
def foo(a, c=3):
    b = 2
    print(locals())
    
foo(1)
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```

Comment: блин круто , а я даже не знал о наличии такого простого метода locals() :)) Вот спасибо вам Наиогромнейшее !!!